# SQL Server Update column automatically

Tags: c#, sql-server

In a SQL Server database, I have a table with 2 columns, `Status` and `ExpiryDate`.

I want a mechanism to turn `Status` to `Expired` when the `ExpiryDate` is over and want to send a mail notification to an email address.

```
UPDATE table 
SET Status = 'expired' 
WHERE ExpiryDate < GETDATE()
```

I know how can I do it via C# code, but how can I automate this?

Like every day the script execute and initiate the email sending process ?
Is it triggers or something different? Can some one help to get the proper term and some insights about the implementation?

Comment: SQL Server agent job?

Comment: Does it have to be in the DB? You could write a Console app that is run as a windows task or a full windows service to do this.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do this with a trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Use a stored procedure (schedule as a job) to update the table and send the email.

To configure the email option go to the Management section in Object Explorer, right-click Database Mail and click Configure Database Mail.

Then take advantage of the [`sp_send_dbmail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) system stored procedure to send mail.

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure that performs

```
UPDATE table 
SET Status = 'expired' 
WHERE ExpiryDate < GETDATE()
```

Then under the SQL Server Agent Node in SQL Server, create a job that runs on the schedule you need.

Be sure to use `sp_send_dbmail` in your stored procedure as well - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx to send your email.